# Displaying result of joining two MySQL tables without duplicates, using DISTINCT or GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, left-join, distinct, group

I have two tables:
`BLOG` table withe scheme
(id_blog, name, content, date, building) and `IMG` table with scheme (id_img, filename, id_blog).

With query below, I've got result of LEFT JOIN tables `BLOG` and `IMG` and it's OK.

```
SELECT b.name, 
       b.content, 
       i.id_blog, 
       i.filename
FROM blog b
LEFT JOIN img i USING(id_blog)
WHERE building IN (2,3)
ORDER BY i.filename DESC
```

My query result:

```
Building A | Warehouse | 1 | pic3.jpg
Building A | Warehouse | 1 | pic4.jpg
Building A | Warehouse | 1 | pic6.jpg
Building B | Store     | 2 | pic7.jpg
Building B | Store     | 2 | pic9.jpg
Building B | Store     | 2 | pic8.jpg
Building C | School    | 3 | pic5.jpg
```

What should I do to get result without duplicates `name`, `content`, `id_blog` columns.

What I need is result below:

```
Building A | Warehouse | 1 | pic6.jpg
Building B | Store     | 2 | pic9.jpg
Building C | School    | 3 | pic5.jpg
```

Comment: You can apply partition by. For simplification you can use with clause and then it will be easier to apply partition by. Something like :   With a as ( your select statement), b as (select *, row_number() over ( partition by name, content, id_blog, filename order by filename desc ) as rn ) select * from b where rn = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT b.name, 
       b.content, 
       i.id_blog, 
       max(i.filename)  as filename
FROM blog b
LEFT JOIN img i USING(id_blog)
WHERE building IN (2,3)
GROUP BY b.name,b.content,i.id_blog
ORDER BY filename DESC;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec3427289fa61d8e9c3551f09ab6bdb9)

Comment: Thanks. It's works! I've tried this way but I got MySQL error:

SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I didn't know I should user Alias with function.

Comment: @Sandowl check the `ORDER BY` clause, I edited the answer. Try and let me know

Comment: There is no need to add MAX() function in ORDER BY. Everythings works fine. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no way to get your desired result given the data (and design) of the IMG table.

If your intention is that each blog will have one and only one img then either delete the eroneous records (ie ib_blog,filename  1,pic3.jpg  1,pic4.jpg) or add a img_filename column to the blog table and get rid of the img table.